# Change label font color on toggle checked state 1-2-3?

Tags: html, toggle, checked

I got a tri-state toggle in my html/css and I want to change the font Color of "SCORE CLOCK CONFIG" to white when the toggle is switched to the specific value (Only changing the color of the selected state). What do I have to do for that? Thanks for any help!

```
<div class="toggle_radio">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
        <input type="radio" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" name="toggle_option">
        <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle"     name="toggle_option">
        <label for="first_toggle"><p>SCORE</p></label>
        <label for="second_toggle"><p>CLOCK</p></label>
        <label for="third_toggle"><p>CONFIG</p></label>
    <div class="toggle_option_slider">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.toggle_radio{
  position: relative;
  border:1.5px solid #58B947;
  margin: 15px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}
.toggle_radio > * {
  float: left;
}
.toggle_radio input[type=radio]{
  display: none;
}
.toggle_radio label{
  font:"Lato Light";
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
.toggle_option_slider{
  z-index: -1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#first_toggle:checked ~ .toggle_option_slider{
  background: #58B947;
  left: 0px;
}
#second_toggle:checked ~ .toggle_option_slider{
  background: #58B947;
  left: 108.5px;
}
#third_toggle:checked ~ .toggle_option_slider{
  background: #58B947;
  left: 218px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.on()` and `.css()` after adding IDs or classes.

```js
$('#first_toggle').on("click", function() {
  $("#1").css("color", "white");
});
```

```css
.toggle_radio {
  position: relative;
  border: 1.5px solid #58B947;
  margin: 15px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 28px;
}

.toggle_radio>* {
  float: left;
}

.toggle_radio input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.toggle_radio label {
  font: "Lato Light";
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 3px 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.toggle_option_slider {
  z-index: -1;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .4s ease;
  -o-transition: all .4s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

#first_toggle:checked~.toggle_option_slider {
  background: #58B947;
  left: 0px;
}

#second_toggle:checked~.toggle_option_slider {
  background: #58B947;
  left: 108.5px;
}

#third_toggle:checked~.toggle_option_slider {
  background: #58B947;
  left: 218px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle_radio">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="first_toggle" name="toggle_option">
  <input type="radio" checked class="toggle_option" id="second_toggle" name="toggle_option">
  <input type="radio" class="toggle_option" id="third_toggle" name="toggle_option">
  <label for="first_toggle"><p id="1">SCORE</p></label>
  <label for="second_toggle"><p>CLOCK</p></label>
  <label for="third_toggle"><p>CONFIG</p></label>
  <div class="toggle_option_slider">
  </div>
</div>
```